# Taking a picture without the image picker (modal view)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to take a picture without displaying the image picker. I use the takePicture method.

Here is my code:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]) {
    UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imageController = ipc;
    [ipc release];

    self.imageController.delegate = self;

    self.imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imageController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    self.imageController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;

    [self.imageController takePicture];
}
```

where imageController is `@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImagePickerController* imageController;`

My class is `@interface PhotoVideo : NSObject <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>`

Unfortunately, the picture isn't taken because `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` is never called.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you still need to *present* the `UIImagePickerController`, as a modal view controller or a popover, before you can use `-takePicture`. You can overlay a custom view though when you don't want to use the standard controls.

Comment: Ok but is there any way to hide the `UIImagePickerController` ?

Comment: As I said, you can overlay a custom view on top of the picker controller's view.

Comment: Oh yes sorry your right. I read too fast.

Thank you for your help!